# Radio buttons live refresh in the customizer

Tags: ajax, css, javascript, theme-customizer

I've added a new section in the customizer with a radio button setting with three options. The new setting adds a CSS class to the site header. Everything works as expected except the live refresh in the customizer. I've tried to change the transport to 'refresh' with no success either.

PHP:

```
// Add header layout setting and control.
$wp_customize->add_section( 'header', array(
    'title'     => __( 'Header', 'theme' ),
    'priority'  => 30,
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_layout', array(
    'default'   => 'header-layout-1',
    'transport' => 'postMessage'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_layout', array(
    'label'     => __( 'Header Layout', 'theme' ),
    'description' => __( 'Applied to the header on wide screens only.', 'theme' ),
    'section'   => 'header',
    'settings'  => 'header_layout',
    'type'      => 'radio',
    'choices'   => array(
        'header-layout-1' => __( 'Header Layout 1', 'theme' ),
        'header-layout-2' => __( 'Header Layout 2', 'theme' ),
        'header-layout-3' => __( 'Header Layout 3', 'theme' )
    )
) ) );
```

JS:

```
api = wp.customize;

// Header.
api( 'header_layout', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to, from ) {
        $( '.site-header' ).removeClass( from ).addClass( to );
    } );
} );
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

The above code works. Apparently, the customizer was loading an old version of the `customize-preview.js` file of the theme, so that's why it was not working. Note to self: don't forget to delete the browser cache when developing.